# Trouble Python username and password application

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an email-like application for a project for my software design class using python. I'm still pretty new to this, so I apologize in advance if this is hard to understand.

I want to make a program where you can either log in with an existing username/password or create a new one. I can't seem to get the program to log in with the existing user, or create a new one. I think the problem I'm having is with the password part. The program recognizes the existing username, but loops back to the first statement "are you a registered user? y/n? press q to quit"

I'm sure there's heaps of errors in here since I'm not very good with Python still. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
users = {}
users["nkk202"] = "konrad"

choice = None
login = None
createPassword = None
createUser = None
createLogin = None




print("Welcome to Kmail. The most trusted name in electronic mail.")
print("\nLet's get started")

while choice != "q":
    choice = input("Are you a registered user? y/n? Press q to quit: ")

    if choice == "q":
        print("Thank you for using Kmail. Goodbye.")

    if choice == "n":
        print("Okay then, let's set up an account for you then.")
        createUser = input("Create login name: ")

        if createUser in users:
             print("I'm sorry, that username is already in use. Please try another!\n")
        else:
             createPassword = input("Enter a password: ")


    elif choice == "y":
        login = input("Enter your username: ")

        if login in users:
           password = input("Enter your password: ")

           if password in users:
               print("Welcome", user, "!")

        else:
            print
            print("I'm sorry, either the password/username was unaccaptable, or does not exist. Please try again. \n")
```

Comment: if password in *users*?

Comment: from what I was reading online, people said to use something like.. users["name1"] = "password1"

Comment: Then you want `if users[login] == password`.

Comment: I think you are in the right track, and as @uselpa said, you need to look closely where yo do iterate and check for values. Also, thank you for making it clear that this is homework assignment. Wish more students seeking help in SO would do the same.

Comment: @rdodev Job is done. Please, write your answer and close the question or just delete it..

Comment: @akaRem what? What job is done?

Comment: @rdodev I though, you found an answer. Or I made a mistake?

Comment: @akaRem No, I didn't post answer or question, was simply encouraging OP to pursue with the suggestions since he or she is very close to the solution.

Comment: Okay I'll give that a shot! Thank you all very much, and Happy Thanksgiving to the Americans on here!